# Powershell - Use two hashtable in function

Tags: powershell

I would like to create groups out of two hash tables

```
$var_computer = @{
    "Notebooks" = "NB";
    "PCs" = "PC";
    }

$var_os = @{
    "Windows10" = "Windows 10*";
    "Windows8.1" = "Windows 8.1*";
    }

function create_groups ($var_computer, $var_os, $path){
    ForEach ($key in ($var_computer).Keys) {
            $new_group_name = "_DEFAULT_" + $key
            if ((Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq $new_group_name} -SearchBase $path) -eq $null) {
                New-ADGroup -name $new_group_name -GroupScope Global -Path $path
            }
```

So that i get

_DEFAULT_Notebooks_Windows10

_DEFAULT_Notebooks_Windows8.1

_DEFAULT_PCs_Windows10

...

How could i add another key in my $new_group_name so that it doesn't start at the first key in my second hash table.
Or would it be easier to have nested hash tables?

Comment: Why multiple hash tables? Just create `PSObject` objects containing whatever properties you want.

Comment: Haven't thought about PSObject, just needed some kind of list that i can use for my functions, so i can use keys for naming and values to identify clients in other parts of my script and add to this groups for example

Comment: What do you mean by "so that it doesn't start at the first key in my second hash table."? Do you only want Windows 10 for PCs, but both OSs for Notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? Foreach OS foreach computer-type

```
$var_computer = @{
    "Notebooks" = "NB";
    "PCs" = "PC";
    }

$var_os = @{
    "Windows10" = "Windows 10*";
    "Windows8.1" = "Windows 8.1*";
    }

foreach ($type in $var_computer.Keys) {
    foreach ($os in $var_os.Keys) {
        $new_group_name = "_DEFAULT_$($type)_$($os)"
        $new_group_name

        #Create group
    }
}
```

Output:

```
_DEFAULT_Notebooks_Windows8.1
_DEFAULT_Notebooks_Windows10
_DEFAULT_PCs_Windows8.1
_DEFAULT_PCs_Windows10
```